# querying subdiv on scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following pseudo website I want to scrape:
I am only interested in the divs of class foo that have a subdiv of class bar.
And then I want to create a request on an href that is right after the subdiv (not inside it)
How do I do that with scrapy?

```
<div class="foo"> ..... </div> /*not interesting */

<div class="foo"> /* interesting - need the href */
  <div class="bar"> .... </div>
  <a href="blabla"></a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

```
all_divs = sel.xpath("//div[@class='foo']")
for div in all_divs:
    div_content = div.extract()
    if 'class="bar"' in div_content:
        link = div.xpath('a/@href').extract()
```

Works,
but I was wondering if there is a more sophisticated/elegant/efficient solution

Comment: edited what I tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use predicates that test children nodes, so that

```
//div[@class="foo"][div[@class="bar"]]/a/@href
```

should achieve the same:

- a `div` with class "foo" (1st predicate),
- that has a `div` child with class "bar" (2nd predicate),
- and selecting `a` nodes of this first `div`, then their "href" attribute (as you wrote already)